How to Re-render a component in +layout.svelte
How to re-render a component in +layout.svelte, whenever the userType changes?
I am expecting to switch a navbar state between login and logout, navbar state depends on currentUserType.i have a store for currenUsertype. i want to show login button when user is logedout and when user login into the account then button should disappear from the navbar dynamically.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can use the +layout.svelte component like any other. That means you subscribe to the store by writing $ in front of it, and then you can just use if.
{#if $currentUserType === "loggedIn"}

And so on.
